# How come modulo gives same result while applying on each step or applying once in end?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

(a<sup>bc</sup>)%n = (((a<sup>b</sup>)%n)<sup>c</sup>)%n = (((a<sup>c</sup>)%n)<sup>b</sup>)%n

Means, result is always same even if I apply on each step or once at end.

For Ex. a=3, b=2, c=3, n=5, always gives answer 4.

**Why it feels weird to me?**

If I assume modulo as clock with numbers from 0-4, we walk on this clock from 0-∞ and always remains on clock. But distance traveled in above cases is very different but still final position is same.

1. 3<sup>6</sup>=729 and final position is 4
2. 3<sup>2</sup>=9, and 4<sup>3</sup>=64, now distance is 9+64=73, much lesser than previous but final position still 4.
3. 3<sup>3</sup>=27, 2<sup>2</sup>=4, here distance is only 31, but final position still 4.

I don't know if I am using this clock process right, but it feels weird and confusing. Can anyone tell me why they gives same result or point me to some resource.

Comment: Being an old user of this site you should have enough knowledge about how to write a question in good mathematical formatting.

Comment: @nmasanta but on Linux fora you don't encode a lot of maths..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true because taking the residue modulo $n$ is a ring morphism from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z{/}n\Bbb Z$. So we can interchange ring operations (like $+,-,\times$ (and their derived operations, like powers) and taking residues modulo $n$. You could formally show it using some recursion on arithmetical expressions, I suppose.

Comment: Mathematical proof is in comment section of this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yjrfm_oRO0w"

Comment: @ParveshMonu Not a very good proof BTW. Read a proper book.